# Vim splits long string into several ones

Tags: c++, vim

Whenever i've tried to type something like :

```
void InsertVertices(const std::vector<Vertex> &vertices);
```

Vim automatically converts it to:

```
void
  InsertVertices(const
    std::vector<Vertex>
    &vertices);
```

and here is my vimrc:

```
set wrapmargin=80
set wrap
" for google codestyle
syntax on 
set shiftwidth=2
"set wrap 
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
```

What should i to to prevent this autoformatting?

*set textwidth=80*
**work** for me, thank you for you time!

Comment: What does `:verb set tw?` say? (mind the interrogation mark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know textwidth must be 0 for wrapmargin to take effect. Maybe you could try explicitly setting your textwidth:

```
set textwidth=0
```

Or use textwidth instead:

```
set textwidth=80
```

Comment: Correct; if `textwidth` is non-zero, `wrapmargin` has no affect. But having either one set to a non-zero number could cause the effect described.

Answer (score 0):

You should examine these options to see if they're contributing to the wrapping behaviour that you describe:

```
set textwidth=0
set wrapmargin=0
```

If either `textwidth` or `wrapmargin` are not zero, they can cause text to wrap to the next line.

```
set formatoptions
```

One of the options set by `formatoptions` may also be having an affect on your wrapping. For reference, my options are set to `tcq` in a new, blank Vim document. (I haven't modified these options from their defaults.) `formatoptions` appears to change with `filetype`, therefore you should examine its value:

```
set filetype
```

You may also want to disable the `wrap` option, just to make sure:

```
set nowrap
```